# Hiding a label using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide the label on my input once I click on it.

HTML

```
<form id="submit" method="get">
  <div class="md-form">
    <label for="getP">Search for Professor</label>
    <input class="tt-query form-control" 
           id="typeValue"
           spellcheck="false"
           autocomplete="off"
           name="getP"
           type="text"/>
  </div>
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block my-4 submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
 <hr>
</form>
```

I'm using the following

```
  $(".form-control").focus(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
  }).blur(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").show();
  });
```

It does nothing to hide the label, although it does fire.

Comment: Good design doesn't rely on relative elements. If you suddenly need to adjust your dom layout or structure you are going to have to change your client side logic as well.  Set an `id` attribute for the label and input so that way they are tied together ;)

Comment: on changing the id to match, it does nothing new.

Comment: Did you adjust your jQuery to also point to that id?

Comment: The code you provided works for me on Chrome 65 and IE1. Make sure you put your script tag at the bottom of the document or wrapped your code inside `$(function(){ ... })`. If it still don't work, try to check the developer console if there is any error.

Comment: Your code works fine in the latest version of Chrome, see: https://jsfiddle.net/xuc6odav/ . Are you sure that's your exact markup on the page?

Comment: For example you'd set your id for the label like `formInputName`. Then replace `$(this)` with `$(this + '#yourID')`.

Comment: Cleaned up formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided does work as you can see below. Please check for errors and ensure you have correctly added Jquery with `` `jQuery exists: ${typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'}` `` in your console.

```js
$(".form-control")
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submit" method="get">
  <div class="md-form">
    <label for="getP">Search for Professor</label>
    <input class="tt-query form-control" id="typeValue" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" name="getP" type="text" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block my-4 submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <hr>
</form>
```

Note that although the method used to toggle the label works, it could be more clearly typed by assigning an id and toggling on focus.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldqvk296/) using your code and it works. Please check if you have included the jquery lib.

```
$(".form-control").focus(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery show / hide is for the none / block display.
Would not you confuse with the principle of visible / invisible?

PS: the `for` attribute in the `<label>` tag refers to the `Id`, not the `name`

```js
$(".form-control") 
  .focus(function () {
    $(this).prev("label").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    // $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
  })
  .blur(function () {
    $(this).prev("label").css('visibility', 'visible');
    // $(this).prev("label").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submit" method="get">
  <div class="md-form">
    <label for="typeValue">Search for Professor</label>
    <input class="tt-query form-control" id="typeValue" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" name="getP"
      type="text" />

  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block my-4 submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <hr>
</form>
```